# How can I get started with cross platform network programming?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, tcp

I'm thinking of purchasing [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Unix-Network-Programming-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0131411551/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1312236326&sr=8-1) to learn more on C/C++ networking programming:

I was just wondering is there/do I need a windows equivalent book (I do plan to code on both OS'). I'm not sure of the difference in the evolution regarding BSD sockets the windows.

I'm mainly buying this to eventually write code which will stream data between computers.

Comment: It is wise of you to learn how to do it in *nix first. Learning how to do it in Windows first would scar your brain.

Comment: Though I haven't used it myself yet, if you're investigating C++ network programming you might want to look at the cross-platform Boost.ASIO library.  And then tell me how it is.  :)   http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

["Porting Socket Applications to Winsock"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Having done both, I'd definitely start out with the BSD version.  Not only will you be learning something useful on both platforms (and others), but you'll have a better feel for what's really going on underneath.

I think the questions you need to ask yourself are:

- How soon do you plan to add Windows to your network programming repertoire, AND
- Do you want your code to be cross-platform

If you want your code to be cross-platform, I'd look at Boost or some other cross-platform network library to get you there quickly.  If you are simply wanting to start out learning about network programming in general and then add Windows network programming specifically to your skillset, I'd start with the BSD API as you've planned and then get a resource for specifically doing this for Windows when you are ready.  When I made the move from Linux to Windows I found it was worth the extra time to learn the Windows way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you can use Windows API to do socket programming, I would recommend you learning [BSD sockets API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) (or POSIX sockets API) and used it in BOTH: Windows **and** Linux.

Windows has great support for BSD sockets API.

And you will greatly benefit from a single code base instead of coding twice the same features. Besides, BSD/POSIX API is also available in many other UNIX flavors (MAC OS X, HP/UP, AI/X, BSD, you name it).

Answer (score 1):

For simple apps, BSD sockets will work just fine in Windows. But for the bells and whistles, I really recommend reading up on "native" winsock. Asynchronous sockets are really nice in GUI apps, and Overlapped I/O is just the bee's knees if you want high speed performance, without having to deal with threads (you can if you want to, but Windows will do it for you).

[This](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/io-strategies.html) is a good read.

Comment: There's a lot of opinion here. There is a lot of high quality production code out there running on select() and poll().

Comment: Well, if you are going to handle many simultaneous connections, then overlapped I/O with completion ports is generally both faster in terms of development and performance. You can easily serve more than 64 connections (which is the default limit of `select()` in winsock). Also, using winsock, it becomes less cumbersome if you have to wait on other I/O and various synchronization objects. That is a harder nut to crack with BSD socket functions. I didn't say there wasn't any high quality production code using `select()` and `poll()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Network Programming for MS Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/5726.aspx). I haven't read this yet, but will definitely do it as it looks very promising.

Comment: It was published quite a long time ago and even the 2002 comments on amazon say there are a lot of mistakes :s

Comment: @Paul I can't say for sure without reading it thoroughly, but I'm currently writing a web-server, so I just glanced over the book and it gave me some usefull clues. And 2002 is not long ago, the main principles remain.

Answer (score 0):

Don't spend your money yet - I haven't personally found a better guide on networking than Beej's.
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/